# Index out of range + Bad Instructions

Tags: swift, layout, uicollectionview

I have a View Controller that has two UICollectionViews and the code below works and displays everything correctly in the simulator. However, when I try to scroll the second UICollectionView, the simulator fails and I receive a fatal error: Index is out of range. It shows this code line as a bad instruction:

```
cell.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: Popu[indexPath.row])



import UIKit

class MainScreen: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var TopCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var BottmView: UICollectionView!

var theList = ["Stanford", "Cal", "Alabama", "USC"]

var Popu = ["Football", "Basketball", "Baseball", "Hockey"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    TopCollectionView.dataSource = self
    TopCollectionView.delegate = self

    BottmView.dataSource = self
    BottmView.delegate = self


    let availableWidth = view.bounds.width - 8 - 4
    let itemSize = availableWidth / 2

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 4, bottom: 6, right: 4)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSize , height: itemSize)

    BottmView.collectionViewLayout = layout


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return theList.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView==self.TopCollectionView {

    let cell:TopImages = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! TopImages

    cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: theList[indexPath.row])

    return cell

}
else
    {
    let cell:PopCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PopUCell", for: indexPath) as! PopCell

    cell.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: Popu[indexPath.row])
    return cell
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This cannot be all the code.

Comment: @ryantxr what do you mean? I have this code and 2 sub classes for Collection Cell. This code runs but it crashes when I try to scroll BottmView.

Comment: I see it now. I missed that it scrolled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning **one** count but you have **two** collections.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView==self.TopCollectionView {
        return theList.count
    } else {
        return Popu.count
    }
}
```